# wait/notify. Why all threads are getting notified?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is a code snippet

```
public class ITC3 extends Thread {
  private ITC4 it;

  public ITC3(ITC4 it){
    this.it = it;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ITC4 itr = new ITC4();
    System.out.println("name is:" + itr.getName());
    ITC3 i = new ITC3(itr);
    ITC3 ii = new ITC3(itr);


    i.start(); ii.start();
    //iii.start();
    try{
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
    itr.start();
  }

  public void run(){
    synchronized (it){
      try{

        System.out.println("Waiting - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        it.wait();
        System.out.println("Notified " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }catch (InterruptedException ie){}
    }
  }
}

class ITC4 extends Thread{
  public void run(){
    try{
      System.out.println("Sleeping : " + this);
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      synchronized (this){
        this.notify();
      }
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
  }
}
```

Output given is

```
Output: 
Waiting - Thread-1 
Waiting - Thread-2 
Sleeping : Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 
Notified Thread-1 
Notified Thread-2
```

In this all threads are getting notified. I am unable to understand the whole output in this
case.

1. Why all threads are getting notified?
2. Why Sleeping is printing `Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
3. Pretty lost in whole working of the program.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955006/java-synchronization-is-doing-auto-notify-on-exit-is-this-expected

Comment: By the way, this code will never do anything sensible because your `synchronized` blocks don't protect any shared state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are synchronizing on an instance of `Thread`. If you check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29), you'll see that the `Thread` instance is notified when its `run` method completes. This is how the `join` mechanism is implemented.

You execute one explicit `notify` call (the one we see in the code), and another implicit `notifyAll` when the thread is done. You could even remove your explicit `notify` and the behavior wouldn't change due to the implicit `notifyAll` at the end.

Comment: i have a question as the itr instances is shared between two threads, will two threads block each other?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "block each other". They are two threads waiting on the same monitor.

Comment: they two are waiting at the same Object, so one should get notified not both, because we are not using notifyAll() here.

Comment: Exactly. My answer explains the rest.

Comment: where in documentation it is written that Thread() instance is notified when run() method completes. I am just trying to check the javadoc. can you provide me the reference of it?

Comment: It's documented in the `join` method. Check the link in my answer under the text "the documentation".

Comment: thankyou very much. I understood the whole concept now. Thankyou so much.

Comment: I am sorry i had commented itr.start(). Anyhow thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. already answered, but you should not syncronize on Thread object.
2. Thread's toString() method returns names of all threads in his ThreadGroup, not only name of current thread.